# Does std::map<key, data> in C++ support native data types like Structures?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

How do I map a key to a native data type like structure?

I wrote this snipped but I couldn't compile it. Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct _list
{
  int a,b;
}list;
map<int,list> test_map;

int main(void)
{
  cout <<"Testing"<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading what compiler had to say?

Comment: Hello on SO! To get better answers on such questions, please provide the exact error your compiler is giving you (along with which compiler you use).

Comment: Line 8: error: reference to 'list' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: `typedef struct` -- Hello, 80's!

Comment: Line 8: error: reference to 'list' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: Your code compiles just fine (after adding `using namespace std;`) on VS2010. Don't you have a real compiler to test on instead of codepad?

Comment: Also, as John Dibling says above, you don't need the `typedef` for using structs in C++, get rid of it, declare your struct as `struct list { /*..*/ };` and you can refer to it as just `list` instead of `struct list`

Comment: i bet he had 'using namespace std' and thats how come he got the collision with list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of problems here:

- You're missing either a `using::std` or `std::map`, so the compiler doesn't know what `map<int,list>` means.
- Assuming you have a `using namespace std` declaration, your typedef `list` might collide with the STL collection of the same name.  Change the name.
- Your `typedef struct _tag {...} tag;` construct is an archaic holdover from the 80's.  It is not necesarry, and frankly rather silly.  It gets you nothing.

Here's your code fixed:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct MyList
{
  int a,b;
};

std::map<int,MyList> test_map;

int main(void)
{
  std::cout <<"Testing"<< std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

map resides in the std:: namespace. Two possible ways to fix this:

```
using namespace std;
// ...
map<int, list> test_map;
```

or

```
std::map<int, list> test_map;
```

I prefer the second method, but it's a purely personal choice.

On a related note, there is no real limitation on what you can put in a map, aside from the fact that they must be copyable/assignable, and that the key type must have a < operator (or you can also provide a comparer functor).

EDIT: Seems like `<list>` is included somewhere, either in `<iostream>` (unlikely) or `<map>` (strange but not impossible). A using namespace std will cause std::list to clash with your own struct. The solution: rename your struct, or remove the using namespace and put std:: where it's needed.

Comment: Line 8: error: reference to 'list' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot to mention that you also need to add std:: before cout and endl.

Answer (score 2):

Added `std` where required.

Renamed list to `mylist` to avoid clash with `std::list`.  Avoid typenames and variable names that clash with common usage.

Now compiles OK in VS2008.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct _list
{
    int a,b;
} mylist;

std::map<int,mylist> test_map;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout <<"Testing"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There's no issue with using your struct in the STL containers provided it's copyable cleanly (copy constructor), assignable (implements `operator=`) and comparable (implements `operator<`).

Comment: but how do insert values in to my test_map. For example how to do for test_map[0] I wanna insert a=1,b=2

Comment: @skokal01 - Define a constructor on `mylist` that takes 2 ints, and then insert into the map like so : `test_map[0] = mylist(int1, int2);`

Comment: @skokal01 - plan on getting v familiar with your STL documentation. There is a ton of advice on this forum too if you search in a targeted way.  You can also insert into the map using insert(make_pair) for example.  The semantics of the [] insert are interesting and can be non-intuitive, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be comming from C. Try this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct list
{
  int a,b;
};

std::map<int,list> test_map;

int main(void)
{
  std::cout <<"Testing"<< std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "You seem to be coming from C"?

Answer (score 0):

`map<int, _list> test_map;` or don't use `list`(much better) as a name of structure. (You probably also have

```
#include <list>
...
using namespace std;
```

somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using codepad at all.

I have done a couple of tests with your code and it seems that

- it is adding an implicit (and unwanted) `using namespace std` --it does not require you to qualify `map`, `cout` or `endl`.
- it is (probably) including more standard headers than you might want, including `#include <list>`.

That means that when the compiler looks at the code it is seeing two `list`, your version and the one in `std`. Because of the using directive, both are in scope in the line where you create the map and the compiler is not able to determine which to use.

Two simple things that you can do: change the name of your type for the simple test to something other than `list` (ouch! the tool forcing your naming choices!) or fully qualify the use:

```
#include <map>
struct list {
   int a,b;
};
std::map< int, ::list > the_map;
// ...
```

Note that *codepad* is adding the include by itself and the using directive, so it will also compile:

```
struct list {
   int a,b;
};
map<int,::list> the_map;
```

But that piece of code is **wrong**